# find difference in two dom elements then make them same

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have two elements :

**Element A :**

```
<div id="myID">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"><div id="ba"></div></div>
  <div id="c"><span id="ca"></span></div>
</div>
```

and **Element B :**

```
<div id="myID">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"><div id="ba"></div></div>
  <div id="c"><span id="ca"></span></div>
  <div id="d"></div>
</div>
```

**Is it possible to find out that `Element B` has more children than `Element A`, then find where is additional element and create it in `Element A`?**

*P.S: In real code new element is loaded with `Ajax Request`, but I don't want to replace all content with loaded content, I need to add only new content and skip existing one.*

*P.S.S : In my current code I have Md5 checksum to check if new content is not the same as existing, but if new content have only little changes it replaces all content and this is the problem for me.*

***A piece of my current code :***

```
 window.processResponse = function(data) {
    // Note : "data" is Ajax responseText;
    if(!data) return false;
    var $data = document.createElement("div");
    $data.innerHTML = data;
    var em = $data.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i = 0; i < em.length; i++)
    {
      var parent = sget(em[i].id); // sget function is : document.getElementById
      if(parent) 
      {
        var html = em[i].innerHTML.replace(/(\s)+/gim, "").replace(/(\n|\r\n)+/gim, "");
        var id = em[i].id;
        savedPages[id] = savedPages[id] || [];
        var _md5 = md5(html);
        if(savedPages[id][0] == _md5) continue;
        savedPages[id] = [_md5, getTime()];
        parent.innerHTML = em[i].innerHTML;
      }
      if(em[i].tagName === "SCRIPT") 
      {
        var code = em[i].innerHTML.replace(/(\s)+/gim, "").replace(/(\n|\r\n)+/gim, "");
        var id = em[i].id;
        savedPages[id] = savedPages[id] || [];
        var _md5 = md5(code);
        if(savedPages[id][0] == _md5) continue;
        savedPages[id] = [_md5, getTime()];
        try{eval(em[i].innerHTML)}catch(ex){log(ex)};
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: There are several ways you ca do that, but in order to provide an optimized one we should know some other details: a) can be the children in addition only at the end like the example, or also in the middle? Have the children always IDs? Can be also that the new elements have less children?

Comment: @ZER0 Hello, for a) children can be in any position, not exactly like in the question; b) Yes children will allways have ID's

Comment: Are you always inserting/removing children? Or do you need to sometimes add/remove deeper descendants?

Comment: Yes, sometimes I will need to add/remove deeper descendants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can optimize it but it depends also in which browser are you running this code.
I assumed the follows:

- All IDs are unique, and you rely on that. You want to compare basically elements that have the same ID, not the same structure.
- As you said, all children have IDs, and you want to compare only children – not nested node
- The elements received from the server have only additional children not less. For removing children, you have to add some other code.
- Therefore, if you have the same number of children, we assume they're the same (to optimize). If this is not true, then you have to implement the removal of children as well

Said that, I believe that this kind of stuff is more suitable on server side, that should send to the client only the part that are actually modified. That what we do usually – or, if we don't care, replace everything.

```
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;

  var root = div.firstChild;
  var children = root.children;

  var documentRoot = document.getElementById(root.id);

  if (documentRoot && documentRoot.children.length < children.length) {
    var node = null;
    var previousNode = null;
    var index = 0;

    while ( node = children[index++] ) {
      var documentNode = document.getElementById(node.id);

      if (!documentNode) {
        if (previousNode)
          documentRoot.insertBefore(node, previousNode.nextSibling);
        else
          documentRoot.insertBefore(node, documentRoot.firstChild);

        documentNode = node;
      }

      previousNode = documentNode;

    }

    previousNode = null;

  } else {
    // probably append as is somewhere

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not so simple.  What if the parent, myID, did not exist in sample A but the child nodes were in both samples indicating 3 layers in the DOM that need to be compared and adjusted?  How would you compare this:

```
<div id="papa">
    <div id="myID">
        <div id="a"></div>
        <div id="b">
            <div id="ba"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="c">
            <span id="ca"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

vs

```
<div id="papa">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b">
        <div id="ba"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        <span id="ca"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case the comparison becomes more complicated.  You will actually need a fully fleshed out XML/HTML language aware diff utility with a merge function.  You can play around with [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/) to demonstrate just how complicated this can get, but unfortunately **it does not have a merge function** so it cannot be a fully automated solution to your problem.